# Flutter authentication WITHOUT Firebase

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart, authentication, mongo-dart

I would like to start a simple application in Flutter to practice with MongoDB and I would like to handle users logins/registrations with username/password storing their credentials in MongoDB.

Before today I always used Flutter together with Firebase and so I always used it to manage authentication.

So what should I do after I checked with MongoDB that credentials are correct?
I mean, how can I make the “authentication” persistent across different screens and even after the app has been closed?

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences or hydrated bloc for saving auth state at local storage.

Comment: Bro, did u solve it by u side?

Comment: Kind of... I didn't used MongoDB but I found [this FOSS project](https://appwrite.io) which is an amazing Firebase alternative both regarding Authentication and Database